# Is Gina Haspel wanted in Europe?

Tags: united-states, politics, government, law-enforcement, internet

In a tweet from Randy Kennedy, then shared on Facebook by Girl du Jour (and then others) it is claimed that President Trump's pick to head the CIA - Gina Haspel - is wanted in Europe for "war crimes". The posts don't specifically say, but presumably these war crimes are water boarding and other "enhanced interrogation techniques" used in the CIA prison she once headed.

Searching the web, I've found nothing to back this claim up. Is it true there is/are a warrant(s) for the arrest of Ms. Haspel on charges of war crimes?

Comment: You're going to need a notable source in order for this to stay.  Just saying "recent postings on social media" is not enough for us to talk about this claim.

Comment: I'm not proposing to close this question yet, as there may be a notable source, but you're going to need to find one.

Comment: These [two (1)](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/national-security/trump-nominates-gina-haspel-to-head-cia-an-agency-veteran-tied-to-use-of-brutal-interrogation-measures/2018/03/13/bd47c8ce-26c6-11e8-874b-d517e912f125_story.html?utm_term=.d92d594eed82) [sources (2)](https://townhall.com/tipsheet/cortneyobrien/2018/03/13/edward-snowden-no-fan-of-the-new-cia-director-n2460518) provided on her Wikipedia page will be helpful for anyone who cares to edit or answer the question.

Comment: Neither of the sources @Dispenser cites, nor any I could find with a quick search claimed that she *is* wanted for war crimes. There is plenty of claims that she committed war crimes and opinions that she *should* be arrested, but I can't find anyone actually saying she IS wanted. Please edit in a link and quote of someone making the claim.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It seems that the [tweet has been deleted](https://twitter.com/statuses/975616204625788928) (presumably because Kennedy rescinded the claim). Do we have any evidence people believe it?

Comment: Ah, yes: he [rescinded the claim](https://twitter.com/randyrocks08/status/975748753700384768).

Comment: Snopes covered this: https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/is-there-a-warrant-for-cia-nominee-gina-haspels-arrest/